# Как правильно передать все checked поля одной формы фильтров через ajax

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring

Пишу интернет-магазин бытовой техники, Архитектура Spring MVC, серверная часть реализована на Spring Boot, клиент с помощью Bootstrap, данные хранятся в PostgreSQL.
Пока функционал фильтров был маленький и товары можно было фильтровть только по цене, бренду и стране проблем не было, я просто передавал значения полей через параметры url запроса (например: http://localhost:8080/tv?sortmin=15000&sortmax=50000&country=Japan&brand=Sony&diag_min=32&diag_max=) а на стороне сервера ловил их с помощью

```
@GetMapping("/tv")
    public String showTV(
            Model model,
            @RequestParam(required = false, name = "sortmin") String sortmin,
            @RequestParam(required = false, name = "sortmax") String sortmax,
            @RequestParam(required = false, name = "brand") String brand,
            @RequestParam(required = false, name = "country") String country,
            @RequestParam(required = false, name = "sortby") String sortby
    ){
        filterService.constructAndFilter(Type.TV, model, sortmin, sortmax, brand, country, sortby);

        return "pages/main";
    }
```

Далее специальный Java-класс FilterService наполняет модель нужными товарами, фильтрует их через stream из возвращает готовую модель с отфильтроваными товарами обратно на страницу.

Данный алгоритм отлично работал пока полей фильтров было несколько, но с расширением функционала магазина фильтров стало очень много и для каждого типа товара фильтры уникальные, в следствии чего возникла очень серьезная проблема как лучше всего передавать большое количество параметров на сервер.

Основная страница фильтров и товаров:
[image: Основная страница фильтров и товаров]

ВОПРОСЫ

1. **Как лучше всего передать массив с параметрами фильтров на
   сервер?**  Я думал использовать jQuery Ajax, что бы по нажатию на любое
   поле, ajax функция проверяла все поля формы, и добавляла в массив
   только checked поля. Есть такой нюанс, что некоторые поля должны иметь несколько выбранных значений, что осложняет дело.
2. **Как правильно принимать такой массив контроллером?**
3. **Как в конце получать модель от сервера на клиенте?**
4. **Какие любые варианты данной проблемы можно использовать вообще?**

P.S. пока знаю JavaScript и jQuery только в теории, спасибо большое за ваше уделенное время.

Comment: в php вроде можно было `value[]` возможно spring тоже может такое обработать

Comment: 1. Лучше всего и правильно было бы передавать через ajax параметры; чтобы добавлять параметры есть несколько способов - формировать строку и потом принимать её контроллером, можно передовать массив и в контроллере через пост уже обрабатывать.
2. если строкой параметры передавать - через get разбирать её, если массив параметров - через post

Comment: А name у чекбоксов групп фильтров представлено в виде массива?

Comment: Попробуй чекбокс интерсептор, работает как чайм.